# Banners that follow user on scroll in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with an article. The article has 2 banners on its right side. One banner sits at the top of the article and the other one at approx 50% of the article. I have an independent script that moves the second banner to the 50% of the article height.

The logic I want to achieve is when user starts scrolling, the first banner gets stuck at the top of the window. When user reaches the second banner, the first one gets left behind and instead, the second banner starts scrolling. Finally at the end of the article the second banner stops. I should also be able to pick up the banners where they left and scroll with them back up. I was able to achieve this, but the twist is that once I scroll to approx 50% of an article, another one loads asynchronously under it and so on indefinitely. This is where I get stuck. Once more articles load, the script gets loaded again and I have trouble determining where in the article have I scrolled and how to the next banners. And every article has its own banners, so they load with the article. See code below:

```
<div class="articles-more__section js-sticky-banners" data-article="{_asset.id}">
<div class="container-fluid--from-md">
<section class="row content">

    {/* The article */}
    <div class="content__main">
        <div class="content__main--pull-top col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            /* 
                Content of an article here
            */
        </div>
    </div>

    {/* Side banners */}
    <aside class="content__aside">

        <div class="js-banner-1">
            /*
                Banner 1 stuff here
            */
        </div>

        {/* Banner 2 */}
        <div class="js-banner-2">
            /*
                Banner 2 stuff here
            */
        </div>
    </aside>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is my js. I use require.js so this is a module that loads when it finds class js-sticky-banners:

```
var StickyBanners = {

options: {
    banner1Class: '.js-banner-1',
    banner2Class: '.js-banner-2'
},

initScroll: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var articleId = $(".js-sticky-banners").last().data('article');
    var article = $('.js-sticky-banners[data-article="' + articleId + '"]');
    var banner1 = article.find(_this.options.banner1Class);
    var banner2 = article.find(_this.options.banner2Class);
    var banner1Pos = banner1.offset().top;
    var banner2Pos = banner2.offset().top;
    var banner2OriginPos = banner2.position().top;
    var banner1Done = false;

    //console.log(article.innerHeight());

    $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 960) {
            actualScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
            console.log("doc: " + actualScrollPos);
            //console.log(article.innerHeight() - banner2.outerHeight(true) - 50);
            console.log(banner1Done);

            //User scrolls to the first banner
            if(actualScrollPos > banner1Pos - 87 && actualScrollPos < banner2Pos - banner1.outerHeight(true) - 50) {
                banner1.addClass("fixed-to-top");
                banner1Done = false;
            } else /*User scrolls back*/{
                banner1.removeClass("fixed-to-top");
            }

            //User scrolls the first banner to the second banner
            if(actualScrollPos > banner2Pos - banner1.outerHeight(true) - 50) {
                banner1.css({top: (banner2OriginPos - banner1.outerHeight(true)), position: 'absolute'});
                banner1Done = true;
            } else /*User scrolls back*/{
                banner1.removeAttr("style");
            }

            //User scrolls to the second banner
            if(actualScrollPos > banner2Pos - 87 && actualScrollPos < article.innerHeight() - banner2.outerHeight(true) - 50 && banner1Done) {
                banner2.removeAttr("style");
                banner2.addClass("fixed-to-top");
                banner2.css({'max-width': '365px'});
            } else /*User scrolls back*/{
                banner2.removeClass("fixed-to-top");    
                banner2.css({top: banner2OriginPos, position: 'absolute'});
            }

            //User scrolls the second banner to the end
            if (actualScrollPos > article.innerHeight() - banner2.outerHeight(true) - 50) {
                banner2.removeClass("fixed-to-top");    
                banner2.css({top: article.innerHeight() - (2* banner2.outerHeight(true)) - 50, position: 'absolute'});
            }
        } else {
            banner1.removeClass("fixed-to-top").removeAttr("style");
            banner2.removeClass("fixed-to-top").removeAttr("style");
        }
    });


},
updateOnDomScan: function () {
    this.initScroll();
},

initOnDomScan: function () {
    this.initScroll();
}
};
```

I tried to put a unique article id to the data attribute and bind all the events to that specific div but it fails anyway. The first article scrolls fine, however the next articles grab the first banners and stop too soon and the second banners never get picked up and are positioned at the end like when I finished scrolling the first article. I hope you understand my problem, in case you did not, I have enclosed an image, where I try to explain it better:
[image]

Comment: Any css with this to show sizes of everything?

Comment: There is no easy way for me to share css as the pages is constructed from multiple less components. I can tell you the heights though. The size of the article varies depending on the length of the text in it. It can be as long as 7500px and as short as 1500px. The content__main has 75% width and content__aside is positioned absolutely with top and right being 0. The position is calculated from its relative parent class "content". The first banner has fixed height of 350px and the second one's height is depending on the content, but usually it is about 680px. Does this help or do you need more?

Comment: @Arcane do you have to support Browsers like IE? Else I would recommend on switching to CSS instead of a JS solution.

Comment: I do, I have to support IE10+, so if you are implying I should use position: sticky, I am out of luck.